# Why doesn't windows copy and paste consider and use all files?

Tags: windows-7, raid

I'm trying to restore my operating system from a back up disk. This used to be a part of a raid 1 array. I reactivated the disk and I have access to the files. The problem is, when I select all the files and check the size, it says 41 GB. When I copy and paste all of it into another volume, it says 18.2 GB. Half the files don't want to copy over. I took ownership of the files, and I even changed my user to owner. Yet problem is still there.

I just tried to rar the disk, and it spammed 2500 errors.
http://pastebin.com/RJJzkW8f

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to figure out what Windows is doing when it comes to this sort of problem, I usually just use a Linux live USB stick to copy and then all works well.

An easy to create and easy to operate live USB is Ubuntu. Follow instructions in the following link to make one. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: hey, that's exactly what I did, but I tried knoppix. I do have ubuntu on a usb stick, but thats an installation iso. How do I run the ubuntu off the flash drive?

Comment: Are you the same person as the OP? If so, you'd be better off sticking to one account. I think any Linux system should work equally well. If you created an Ubuntu installation USB you can boot from it and select "try Ubuntu" then you can use it as if you'd installed it.

Comment: Im getting a nasty problem where the linux cp process stalls. Its happening now in ubuntu and it happened in knoppix. 
Well I had issues using the account since my main computer is down and i dont know the password.

Comment: I'm don't have a good idea of how to fix this. Regarding your password problem: Which OS is your main computer running? Bypassing the pw on Ubuntu or Windows is a piece of cake, let me know if you need advice with that. You could consider asking a new question for it if it hasn't already been answered on superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Is Windows Explorer showing hidden *system* files? It seems like the Windows Copy command doesn't work with system+hidden files, unless you change the setting in Folder Options. Please note, that there is different behavior for files with the hidden attribute vs. files with the hidden *and* system attributes.

However, I just verified that **it does in fact work on Windows 10**. So, that wouldn't be your problem if you are you using Windows 10?

**xcopy**

You can try using `xcopy` from a command prompt. xcopy has been included with Windows since, I don't know, Windows 95 or something... Here is an example where d:\ is your old drive and c:\ is the new drive:

```
xcopy d:\ c:\restored\ /Y /Z /H /R /E
```

**Beyond Compare**

I personally would use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php) for that. There is a free trial version and the purchase price is worth every penny and so much more! (I have no affiliation with Scooter Soft, the makers of Beyond Compare, other than being a extremely satisfied *paying* customer..)

The great thing about using Beyond Compare is that it lets you visually see the differences of every file and folder. It shows which files are missing (file is blue when the other side is missing), newer/older (one file is red when newer than the other side), different (both files are red), and more..

Here is an example of using Beyond Compare showing the difference between hidden and hidden+system files..

The picture below shows the two directory structures and their differences. Just like Explorer, Beyond Compare shows hidden files by default, but not system+hidden files. Note the red arrow points to a hidden file `(h)`. 
[image]

In the 'Session Settings' dialog, uncheck the 'Exclude hidden operating system files' option to show everything.
[image]

See the full/complete difference here! Note the bluish/cyan arrows point to a file with the hidden *and* system attributes `(sh)` while the red arrow points to only hidden `(h)`. 
[image]

Comment: i've been using windows 7. might be worth it just to install windows 10 to move it lol

Comment: Windows 10 is far superior to all previous versions of Windows; you definitely should try it out as it is still a free upgrade.

Comment: Whatever version of Windows you have, DO check out Beyond Compare. You will *not* regret it. I've been using it since the early 2000's (Windows 2000) and they now have versions for Mac and Linux as well. It is my most used application/utility.. It's simply fantastic!